# jquery выбор элемента по клику

Tags: jquery, url, img, click

Есть разметка

```html
<div class="img-wrapper">
  <img src="/img21.jpg" alt="" width="100%">
  <div class="eclipse"  onclick="showImg();">
    <div><span>+</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Таких **блоков много**, мне нужно при нажатии на .eclipse или его любой дочерний элемент, получить url картинки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так будет более универсально:

```js
$(".eclipse").click(function(){
   var source = $(this).parent().find("img").attr("src");
   console.log(source);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="img-wrapper">
  <img src="/img21.jpg" alt="" width="100%">
  <div class="eclipse">
    <div><span>+</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```